# Auxiliary NSPanel changes the color of the parent window's toolbar separator

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nspanel

When I have an `NSWindow` with a toolbar and an auxiliary `NSPanel`, then the main window's toolbar separator becomes black when the panel is made key :

[image]
[image]

[You can find an example project here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqj08t7r2cfci1g/SeparatorSabotage.zip?dl=0)

Why does this occur? All is fine if I use an `NSWindow` instead of an `NSPanel`. I tested it on Yosemite (10.10.5).

Comment: This occurs because an `NSPanel` can't become the main window, so I ended up with an `NSWindow` that is main but not key, and that combination would make its toolbar separator black. It can be solved by calling `-resignMain` on the main window as its panel becomes key (eg. within `-windowDidResignKey:`).

Comment: Filed it as a bug (#26898161). (*Edit* : It's been solved in the most recent OS, Sierra).